# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) while running django tests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

Django test throws value error every time i try to input data in the test request

```
req_body = {"Value1":"Value1", "Value2":"Value2"}
request = self.client.get(self.getSingleData_url, data= json.dumps(req_body), content_type='application/json')
```

I have tried data = req_body but it returns an empty {} to the endpoint
[Complete Value error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xONy.png)

I have tried using, other ways to pass data, but once it is passed as json it throws Value Error

Comment: `self.getSingleData_url` should be a url, check if its a method and if so use `self.getSingleData_url()` instead

Comment: It’s a url, I have used reverse(“getSingleData”) to get the url.